# Changing the background colour of a javafx button disables hover, focused etc

Tags: css, button, javafx

I would like to change the background color of a javafx button in my application. I am doing so through a stylesheet which is attached to the pane the button is located in. Here is the CSS:

```
.button {
-fx-background-radius: 0;
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #dbdbdb);
-fx-border-color: black;
}
```

However, while this does work, it also appears to disable default behaviour of the button such as the background changing colour when the mouse hovers over it, or when the button is clicked. If I remove the line from my css where I change the background colour, this behaviour works again.

I would like to be able to change the background colour but keep the default behaviour of the button when it is hovered, clicked etc. How can I do this?

Comment: If you were using a plain color I would suggest setting the `-fx-base` looked-up color, but trying that myself led to some `ClassCastException`s in other places. You may have to manually implement the behavior via `.button:armed {...}` and `.button:hover { ... }`.